# Using event listener to get age in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function getAge(dateString) {
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
        return age;
    }
```

I have this code in my Javascript Script and am trying to find how to show the birthdate given an input on a form in html. Is there an event listener i can use to pass this function inside the input to grab the date and calculate the age?

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input-age" />
<button onclick="getAge()">Calculate Age</button>
```

JS

```
function getAge() {
    var dateString = document.getElementById('input0age').value;
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Or event listener

```
var input = document.getElementById('input-age');

input.addEventListener('input', function() {
   getAge(input.value)
});

function getAge(dateString) {
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't print on the html form?

Comment: Once you have the value, you can show it at any place using selector path. `document.getElementById('output').value = age;`

Comment: is this for the first option or second option you recommended?

Answer (score -2):

I've become a big fan of the [moment](http://momentjs.com/) library.  Using that library, computing age is as simple as:

```
moment().diff( moment( dateString ),'years');
```

where dateString is something like: 'YYYY-MM-DD'.  To parse other date formats, you'll have to use an appropriate parsing format on the constructor, like:

```
moment().diff( moment( dateString, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ), 'years' );
```

where dateString is in that MM/DD/YYYY format.  But including moment.js in your code makes this stuff pretty braindead to do.

Comment: While it may be useful this doesn't answer the question

Comment: The question was about how to run the code in response to a user input, not about how to perform the age calculation.